# Finding Records Using awk Command using math score

Tags: unix, awk

Write the unix command to display all the fields of students **who has score more than 80 in math as well as math score should be top score among all subjects, moreover output should be in ascending order of std(standard)of the students**.

INPUT:

```
roll,name,std,science_marks,math_marks,college
1,A,9,60,86,SM
2,B,10,85,80,DAV
3,C,10,95,92,DAV
4,D,9,75,92,DAV
```

OUTPUT:

```
1|A|9|60|86|SM
4|D|9|75|92|DAV
```

myCode:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=',' ; OFS="|"} {if($4<$5 && $5>80){print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}}'
```

but I'm getting unexpected token error please help me.

```
    Error Message on my Mac System Terminal:
awk: syntax error at source line 1
     context is
        BEGIN >>>  {FS=, <<< 
    awk: illegal statement at source line 1
```

Comment: `print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}` just do `print}`. Note the `"`. Notice how `FS=”,”` differs from ` `OFS="|"`

Comment: It'd be much more useful if you tell us the actual error message instead of your summary of it - `unexpected token error`. I see this question quickly mutated from `how do I fix my syntax error` to `yeah I figure out my silly mistake, but what if I want the output as ascending order`. Please don't post [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/361691).

Comment: @Ed Morton, Sorry for your inconvenience, Now I have successfully edit the question with precise  error so that future viewer can not have this issue and figure out the problem quickly. Thanks for your words...

Comment: Please format the error message just like you did your code and sample input/output. The code you posted now is different from the code you had originally (your previous code used `FS=”,”` while your new code uses `FS=','`) - they're both wrong but now the comments and answer you got about the delimiter you were using don't make sense. Also the answer you accepted isn't the answer to the question you asked above, it's the answer to the question you later asked in a comment. This question is kind of a mess.

Comment: Sir, I have edited original post that I raised initially i.e. FS='   ' and keep the things original, May be someone had changed this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. This answer doesn't hard code the field number it gathers column which has math in it and checks for rest of the lines accordingly then.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=","
  OFS="|"
}
FNR==1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i=="math_marks"){ field=i }
  }
  next
}
{
  for(i=3;i<=(NF-1);i++){
    max=(max>$i?(max?max:$i):$i)
  }
  if(max==$field && $field>80){ $1=$1; print }
  max=""
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                               ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                              ##Starting BEGIN section of code here.
  FS=","                                            ##Setting field separator as comma here.
  OFS="|"                                           ##Setting output field separator as | here for all lines.
}
FNR==1{                                             ##Checking condition if its first line then do following.
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){                               ##Going through all fields here.
    if($i=="math_marks"){ field=i }                 ##Checking if a field value is math_marks then set field to tht field numner here.
  }
  next                                              ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  for(i=3;i<=(NF-1);i++){                           ##Going through from 3rd field to 2nd last field here.
    max=(max>$i?(max?max:$i):$i)                    ##Creating max variable which checks its value with current field and sets maximum value by comparison here.
  }
  if(max==$field && $field>80){ $1=$1; print }      ##After processing of all fields checking if maximum and field value is equal AND math number field is greater than 80 then print the line.
  max=""                                            ##Nullifying max var here.
}
'  Input_file                                       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code has double quotes of wrong encoding:

```
                        here
                        | |
                        v v
$ busybox awk 'BEGIN{FS=”,” ; OFS="|"} {if($4<$5 && $5>80){print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}}'
awk: cmd. line:1: Unexpected token
```

Replace those and your code works fine.